# How to call ruby from java in cloud foundry?

Tags: java, ruby, cloud-foundry

I have a requirement where i need to call/trigger the ruby ETL program from java code in the cloud foundry environment. will cloudfoundry supports 2 different buildpacks to run on single application instance. Is it possible to run java and ruby processes on the single instance in cloud foundry. I'm new to cloud foundry any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might look at https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.  It should let you run both build pack's.  Official support for multi-build packs in CF is coming.  You can see the proposal here.  https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/archives/list/cf-dev@lists.cloudfoundry.org/message/SF5WGRYECAC6ZZGAL7VKAUFJXNENR7CC/

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to have programs written in different programming languages communicate with each other is using REST. Also if asynchronous communication is preferred, you may want to exchange messages via a message broker (e.g. RabbitMQ).

I would recommend deploying two different apps (one written in Ruby and the other written in Java) and have the ruby app expose a REST endpoint that can be triggered by your java app. You could secure this endpoint using some authentication mechanism (e.g. HTTP Basic).

The possibility of running 2 different buildpacks with a single application does, to the best of my knowlege, not exist. Also this does not seem to be a clean approach in my eyes.